# EXEC sp_executesql @sql limitation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having problem with executing dynamic SQL Server code.

I have an insert into temp table and the number of chars is more than 4000.
I tried to split into two variables and then concatenated them but problem is

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
                   N'@DimStartDate int, @DimEndDate bigint',
                   @DimStartDate, @DimEndDate;
```

I found on net that `EXEC(@sql1+@sql2)` is solution but I really need input parameters. How can I solve this?

Comment: Using things like `sp_executesql` should be a last resort really. Dynamic SQL is often dangerous and there's frequently a better alternative. Do you really have to execute such huge blocks of SQL?

Comment: If your query is larger than 4K, you have a serious problem. The query needs *serious* refactoring and simplification. What does the query look like and why should it be dynamic SQL? Why not an `INSERT INTO .... VALUES` statement, `INSERT ... SELECT` or insert from a TVP, or ..... ?

Comment: Classic example of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: `@sql` longer than 4,000 characters shouldn't be a problem if you're defined the data type properly. Where exactly is it getting truncated? Can you show a repro and better describe the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidG Dynamic SQL is only dangerous if written poorly; raw string concatenation, not quoting objects, parameter injection, etc. Dynamic SQL can be just as "safe" as non-dynamic SQL provided it's written well. The same as SQL in a application is "dangerous"; it is ft it's written poorly but a well parametrised query is fine. Dynamic SQL can be a very powerful tool, provided it's used correctly.

Comment: @Larnu Indeed, which is why I said it's *often*  dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with a similar issue before, like below. Basically you need to separate your main query into pieces, then combine them in the end and use sp_EXECUTESQL to run your dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @SQL_Part1 varchar(4000);       
DECLARE @SQL_Part2 varchar(4000);
DECLARE @SQL_Part3 varchar(4000);
DECLARE @SQL_Part4 varchar(4000);
DECLARE @SQL_Part5 varchar(4000);
DECLARE @SQL_FullQuery nvarchar(MAX);

.. set your queries...

SET @SQL_FullQuery = CAST(@SQL_Part1 + @SQL_Part2 + @SQL_Part3 + @SQL_Part4 + @SQL_Part5 as nvarchar(MAX));
EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @SQL_FullQuery;
```

Comment: It worked already, in SQL Server 2014, I copied and pasted from a running example, tbh. @AaronBertrand. For different versions, please try to define all the splitted parts as nvarchar.

Comment: This is surprising. You are casting the Full_Query to NVARCHAR(max) while combining the splitted parts, right?

Comment: Sorry, no, I did not do the cast, I did not see it off the screen. Just don't see the point of defining any of the parts as the wrong data type.

Answer (score 1):

I have had no problem with `sp_executesql` on strings very long strings.  You simply need to declare the query to be long enough:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
```

You can have an error inserting into a table if the *row length* is too long for the table.  That would have nothing to do with the dynamic statement.  The maximum length of a row is limited in SQL Server -- although you can use long strings and blobs to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly where the problem is. SQL Server will happily execute more than 4,000 characters, so your SQL must be getting truncated somewhere else. Here is an example where I've manually built up a batch that is more than 4,000 characters total so you can see that all three `SELECT` statements run and if you copy and paste the middle result you'll see it has the y at the end:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT 1;'
  + N'SELECT ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), REPLICATE('x', 4096)) + N'y'';';
  + N'SELECT 2;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Results:

[image]